# How to control the numbers of points in the range of a plot

Tags: plotting

Consider the following code:

```
fun[x_] := x^2;
Plot[fun[x], {x, -4, 4}]
```

which simply plots a parabola for the range of -4 to 4. I don't know how many points between -4 and 4 Mathematica uses to plot the function?
My question is how can I control this number? In fact I have a complicated function which its evaluation takes a long time. On the other hand I need to plot it in range of 0 to 4 to see its shape. When I try `Plot` command in the range of `{0,4}` it takes a very very long time to get the curve (it has never finished), so I want to reduce number of points. I took a look on the options of `Plot` command but I didn't find my desire one. Any idea?

Comment: see [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

Comment: try also `Plot[Evaluate @ yourcomplicatedfunction[x], {x, -4, 4}]`

Comment: @kglr what does `Evaluate` command do?

Comment: Another thing you might try is to define the function as fun[x_] = x^2; (remove the colon before the equals). This may be why the plotting is so slow.

Comment: I meant, just in case, you have a case like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`. For example

```
fun[x_] := x^2;
Plot[fun[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: `PlotPoints` is the number of points?

Comment: ```PlotPoints``` is the number of initial sampling points. ```MaxRecursion``` the number of times the sampling is iterated. As an example, the options ```PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 0``` and ```PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 2``` give the same answer.